# Ember.Map : are the keys are really ordered?

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to use the new Ember.Map object and I wondering whethere the keys are really ordered since they are stored in a Ember.OrderedSet.

If I iterate over the map like :

```
map.forEeach(function(key,val){
 console.log(key);
})
```

can I expect to see the keys in ascending or descending order ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the source for Ember.Map#forEach:

"The keys are guaranteed to be iterated over in insertion order."